# Json representation of objects returned from @RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}



@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Country extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
    @JsonManagedReference
    List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();


    public Country(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class City extends BaseEntity {


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    Country country;

    public City(String name, Country country) {
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
    }
}


@RestController
public class CityController {
    private final CityRepository cityRepository;

    public CityController(CityRepository cityRepository) {
        this.cityRepository = cityRepository;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = {"cities"})
    public List<City> getCities() {
        List<City> cities = cityRepository.findAll();
        return cities;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"cities/{country}"})
    public List<City> getCities(@PathVariable String country) {

        List<City> cities = cityRepository.findByCountryNameIgnoreCase(country);

        return cities;
    }  

}
```

The problem with that is that when a @RestController returns something it looks like this:

```
[{},{}]
```

There are two cities in two different countries. What can I try next?

Comment: Can you please share Country entity class as well.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson by default will only deserialize the properties that has public getter or annotated with `@JsonProperty`. Now your `City` class does not have any public getters or  `@JsonProperty` annotated on any of its properties , so no properties will be deserialised into the JSON and you get `{}` for each city.

The learning point here is that putting `@Getter` on the child class will NOT generate a getter for the parent properties. Depending on what you want to do , you can simply add `@Getter` on the `BaseEntity` to make it also create a getter for the `BaseEntity` 's properties :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
public class BaseEntity {
   
}
```

It will affect all the children entities that extends `BaseEntity` and make their JSON representations also include all the properties from the `BaseEntity`

On the other hand if you just want only `City` include the `BaseEntity` 's properties but not the other `BaseEntity` 's children, you can create the corresponding getter for `City` only :

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class City extends BaseEntity {


   public String getName(){
     return this.name;
   }

   public Integer getId(){
     return this.id;
   }

}
```